# How to join only the string elements inside a nested list

Tags: python, string, list, concatenation

Here, I'm having a nested list which have both strings and integer values, How to join only the string values together?

```
my_list = [['Advertising', 'Revenue', 963333, 1013332, 49999, '68.31%\n'],
           ['Total', 'Suburban', 'Revenue', 17882085, 18795466, 913381, '69.55%\n']]
```

I tried using the below code, but I'm not getting the exact output

```
for i in my_list:
    for j in i:
        if type(j) == str:
            l = '_'.join(j)
            print(l)
```

Expected output:

```
[['Advertising_Revenue', 963333, 1013332, 49999, '68.31%\n'],
 ['Total_Suburban_Revenue', 17882085, 18795466, 913381, '69.55%\n']]
```

can anyone please help me with this,
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Please read https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236/why-is-can-someone-help-me-not-an-actual-question and [ask]. What result *did* you get from your code? How is that different from the expected output, and why do you think this happens? Also, did you try to write out the intended logic of the program, in plain English words? Did you try drawing a diagram with pencil and paper? It's important to think clearly about the program logic. For example, when you use the `join` method, what is the rule that tells you which strings should be `join`ed? Does your code try to implement that rule?

Comment: Also, I don't understand your description of the problem. I think the expected output should instead look like `[['Advertising_Revenue_68.31%\n', 963333, 1013332, 49999],
 ['Total_Suburban_Revenue_69.55%\n', 17882085, 18795466, 913381]]`. Why is that wrong? What is the rule that tells you *not* to join up the percentage strings like that? What is the *actual* rule telling you what to join up?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are assigning `l`, but doing nothing with it.

You basically need two loops, first one to iterate the lists in the outer list, and the second list to iterate the values in the inner list.

```py
result = []
while my_list:
    row = my_list.pop(0)
    cols = []
    strng = []
    while row:
        val = row.pop(0)
        if isinstance(val, str):
            strng.append(val)
        else:
            if strng:
                cols.append('_'.join(strng))
                strng = []
            cols.append(val)
    else:
        cols.append('_'.join(strng))
    result.append(cols)
```

```py
>>> result
[['Advertising_Revenue', 963333, 1013332, 49999, '68.31%\n'], ['Total_Suburban_Revenue', 17882085, 18795466, 913381, '69.55%\n']]
```

Comment: This isn't the expected output.

Comment: @SorousHBakhtiary, Thank you for pointing out. I had also not noticed it, but that's fixed now.

Answer (score 0):

Keep a buffer s, append the buffer s and empty it when you see an int

```py
my_list = [['Advertising', 'Revenue', 963333, 1013332, 49999, '68.31%\n'],
           ['Total', 'Suburban', 'Revenue', 17882085, 18795466, 913381, '69.55%\n']]
ll = []
for l in my_list:
    s, l1 = [], []
    for e in l:
        if type(e) == str:
            s.append(e)
            continue
        if s:
            l1.append('_'.join(s))
            s = []
        l1.append(e)
    if s:
        l1.append('_'.join(s))
    ll.append(l1)
print(ll)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
my_list = [['Advertising', 'Revenue', 963333, 1013332, 49999, '68.31%\n'],
           ['Total', 'Suburban', 'Revenue', 17882085, 18795466, 913381, '69.55%\n']]

result = []
for sublist in my_list:
    result_sublist = []
    prev_is_string = False
    for item in sublist:
        cur_is_string = isinstance(item, str)
        if prev_is_string and cur_is_string:
            result_sublist[-1] += "_" + item
        else:
            result_sublist.append(item)
        prev_is_string = cur_is_string
    result.append(result_sublist)

print(result)
```

Comment: This doesn't produce the expected output

Answer (score 0):

Try :

```
    my_list = [['Advertising', 'Revenue', 963333, 1013332, 49999, '68.31%\n'],
           ['Total', 'Suburban', 'Revenue', 17882085, 18795466, 913381, '69.55%\n']]

res = []
continuous_strings = []
nested_list = []
for lst in my_list:
    for item in lst:
        if isinstance(item, str):
            continuous_strings.append(item)
        else:
            if continuous_strings:
                new_item = '_'.join(continuous_strings)
                nested_list.append(new_item)

            nested_list.append(item)
            continuous_strings = []

    nested_list.append('_'.join(continuous_strings))
    continuous_strings = []
    res.append(nested_list)
    nested_list = []

print(res)
```

output :

```
[['Advertising_Revenue', 963333, 1013332, 49999, '68.31%\n'], ['Total_Suburban_Revenue', 17882085, 18795466, 913381, '69.55%\n']]
```